# Presence of .htaccess File in Root Directory When Using Wordpress blog in Subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, robots.txt, canonical-link

I have an .htaccess file in the root directory of all my sites which handles canonical rewrites. The entire content of the .htaccess file is as follows:

```
Options +Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

The trouble is, when I install a Wordpress blog in a subdirectory (/blog) the WP blog becomes inoperable. I cannot log into the wp-admin area. My host tells me that this is because of the .htaccess file in the root. Therefore this needs to be deleted.

So how do I achieve the same canonical URL rewrite instructions if I can't have an .htaccess file in the root? Can I have these instructions in a robots.txt file in the root? Or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you document root is `/var/www/my-site/` and you want to have wordpress in `/var/www/my-site/blog` you need to do the following:

1.) Create an `index.php` file the following content and put it into `/var/www/my-site`

```
<?php
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
    require('./blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

2.) Put the following .htaccess into `/var/www/my-site`

```
# Redirect http://example.com to http://www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Now the way you access your admin area is http://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin

Then in your dashboard, go to the settings and set `WordPress Address URL` to `http://www.example.com/blog` and the `Site URL` to `http://www.example.com`